# Mounting a USB Stick at desktop level

Tags: usb

I can't figure out why it seems to be so hard to mount a usb stick in Ubunutu. I am running 14.04 LTS on a chromebook. When I insert a usb it comes up in the tool bar and I have to enter my admin password. Then it disappears and I get the error "Unable to Mount USB NAME', operation was cancelled. How can I get usb sticks to mount correctly so I can use them at desktop level.
fdisk -l shows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 15.5 GB, 15518924800 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14800 cylinders, total 30310400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/dev/sda` refers to the stick you are going to use, it has an empty partition table. It cannot be mounted, the error is to be expected. Use `fdisk` to make a partition on the device with <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>, then `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1` to format this partition.

Afterwards, your system should be able to mount automatically without issues.